# GWT java Numbercell Formatted

Tags: java, gwt, celltable

I have here my Numbercells I want to add doubles to it e.g "1.20" but all I see is 1.
How can I format them for the celltable?

```
    Column<dateiles, Number> column = new Column<dateiles, Number>(new NumberCell()) {
        @Override
        public Number getValue(dateiles object) {
            return object.sum;
        }
    };
    cellTable.addColumn(column, "Numbercells");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NumberFormat format = NumberFormat.getDecimalFormat().overrideFractionDigits(2);

Column<dateiles, Number> column = new Column<dateiles, Number>(new NumberCell(format)) {
    @Override
    public Number getValue(dateiles object) {
        return object.sum;
    }
};
```